# How to generate <Text /> component in loop using react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I would like to know how can I can generate components from a variable which stores an array of strings, with a loop (or something similar). For example, I have an array:

```
const arr = ['Hello', 'Awesome', 'Stack','Over','Flow', 'Have', 'A', 'Nice', 'Day'];
```

and I wrote this method:

```
function renderT() {
  return arr.map(obj => {
    <Text>{obj}</Text>;
  });
}
```

and I then call it in the `return` statement of my `render()` method:

```
return (
  <View style={styles.row}>{renderT()}</View>
)
```

As result I don't have any error or text on the screen. I tried to use different kind of loop `for`, `forEach`, `map` and it didn't work. Could you please point me or suggest me the right way how can I implement it?

Comment: The map function should have a return value. Did you try return arr.map(obj => return {
    <Text>{obj}</Text>;
  });

Comment: You are almost there: 1. in renderT, where is `arr` defined? 2. replace the curly braces in the `map` function so it will actually return something 3. add a `key` prop to each `Text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some a subtleties to be aware of that if missed, will be causing errors and/or unexpected behaviour. Consider the following adjustments to your code, which should address the run-time errors:

```
function renderT() {

  // Ensure arr is defined in scope of, or is "visible" to, renderT()
  const arr = ['Hello', 'Awesome', 'Stack','Over','Flow', 'Have', 'A', 'Nice', 'Day'];

  return arr.map((obj, index) => {
    // Compose a unique key for the text element. A unique key is need when 
    // rendering lists of components
    const key = index;

    // Add return to ensure the text element is returned from map callback
    return <Text key={key}>{obj}</Text>;
  });
}
```

Something to be aware of is the `key` prop - this should be supplied for components that are rendered in a list (ie, `<Text>` in your case).

The reason for the `key` prop being needed is [detailed here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html). Each `key` per item rendered must be unique - generally you should avoid using the `index` of a mapping callback, however seeing the uniqueness of values in `arr` cannot be guaranteed, [it would be necessary](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Hope that helps!

Comment: @MatzHeri you're very welcome - all the best with your project :)

Answer (score 1):

You should replace

```
function renderT() {
  return arr.map(obj => {
    <Text>{obj}</Text>;
  });
}
```

by this:

```
function renderT(arr) {
  return arr.map(obj => {
    return <Text>{obj}</Text>;
  });
}
```

and this:

```
return (
  <View style={styles.row}>{renderT()}</View>
)
```

by this:

```
return (
  <View style={styles.row}>{renderT(arr)}</View>
)
```

The two errors were the missing return and the missing argument in your function renderT. Then you have to call your function with the right argument (your array).

Answer (score 1):

Your `map` function on your `arr` is not returning anything, that's why you're not visioning any texts.

Try to replace your function `renderT()` by:

```
function renderT() {
  return arr.map(obj => (<Text>{obj}</Text>));
}
```

(just replace the `{}` around your `<Text />` value by `()`)